# Are there formulas for $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

So far, I have seen the half angle formula (i.e.)

$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}$$

Is there a way to find $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ in terms of $\sin\theta$ and/or $\cos\theta$ (i.e. a closed form solution)?

Comment: You have gotten it wrong. It's $\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1-\cos \theta}{2}$

Comment: Oops, sorry, a typo! Just fixed it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formulae of $\sin 3A$ and $\cos 3A$ and their derivations?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar I have tried that. Replacing $A$ by $A/3$ in the formulae for $\sin3A$ and $\cos3A$ gives a complicated mess.

Comment: @impopularGuy, it seems like there's no closed form, is it?

Comment: @impopularGuy now that I realize, my approach doesn't give a closed form. You can try and solve the cubic generated though.

Comment: How about $\cos{x/3}=(e^{ix/3}+e^{-ix/3})/2$ ? Replace $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

Comment: @impopularGuy then it strays into the territory of complex numbers. And taking cube root of a complex number is not that easy.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1552459/585410)

Comment: The knowledge in my link is super advanced, and it may not necessarily apply to all $\theta$...

Comment: If you don't accept Cardano's formula for the roots of a cubic (coming from triple angle formula) then there is no formula. This is because an approach to solving a cubic is also to use that same triple angle formula, reducing solving a cubic to find $\cos(\theta/3)$. In other words, the two problems are equivalent. Either you accept complex third roots, or accept that there is no formula. Yes, I'm aware that for some cubics you would rather use hyperbolic cosine as opposed to the trig cosine, but that's not really relevant.

Comment: Mind you. In the same sense the ability to calculate half-angle trig functions is equivalent to the ability to solve quadratics (or to take square roots).

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytic formula for $\sin\frac{\theta}{3}$ & $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}$ . But the value of $\sin\frac{\theta}{3}$ & $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}$ can be derived in terms of $\sin\theta $ & $\cos\theta$ using triple angle formula (which may also give complex roots) as follows
$$\sin3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$$
setting $3x=\theta$ or $x=\frac{\theta}{3}$ in above trig. identity, 
$$\sin\theta=3\sin \frac{\theta}{3}-4\sin^3\frac{\theta}{3}$$$$\boxed{4\sin^3\frac{\theta}{3}-3\sin \frac{\theta}{3}+\sin\theta=0}$$
Similarly,
$$\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$$
Setting $3x=\theta$ or $x=\frac{\theta}{3}$ in above trig. identity, 
$$\boxed{4\cos^3\frac{\theta}{3}-3\cos \frac{\theta}{3}-\cos\theta=0}$$

Comment: Couldn't you use Cardano's formula to give analytical solutions, at least for certain intervals of $\theta$?

Comment: What @KyleMiller says. How so would a cubic equation not have a closed form solution?

Comment: Absolutely right. there was mistake. Thanks @JensRenders